# Infrasctructural costs of Thread.sleep() vs LockSupport.parkNanos()

Tags: java, multithreading

While running the following benchmark on Java 11 (Linux and MacOS):

```java
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
public class ThreadSleepVsParkNanosBenchmark {

  @Benchmark
  public void sleep1ms() throws Exception {
    Thread.sleep(1);
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void parkNanos1ms() {
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(1));
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void parkNanos500us() {
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toNanos(500));
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void parkNanos100us() {
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toNanos(100));
  }
}
```

I've found out that the costs of running `Thread.sleep(1)` and `LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(1))` i.e. the overhead of suspending and revoking the thread are pretty much the same on both platforms. But the overhead of `LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toNanos(100))` is significantly lower:

```
Linux
Benchmark                                                 Mode  Cnt        Score      Error  Units
ThreadSleepVsParkNanosBenchmark.parkNanos100us            avgt  100      159.775 ±    0.248  us/op
ThreadSleepVsParkNanosBenchmark.parkNanos500us            avgt  100      612.971 ±    0.578  us/op
ThreadSleepVsParkNanosBenchmark.parkNanos1ms              avgt  100     1103.372 ±    4.685  us/op
ThreadSleepVsParkNanosBenchmark.sleep1ms                  avgt  100     1119.566 ±    0.940  us/op

MacOS
ThreadSleepVsParkNanosBenchmark.parkNanos100us            avgt  100      156,696 ±     6,977  us/op
ThreadSleepVsParkNanosBenchmark.parkNanos500us            avgt  100      752,520 ±    23,203  us/op
ThreadSleepVsParkNanosBenchmark.parkNanos1ms              avgt  100     1508,832 ±     7,580  us/op
ThreadSleepVsParkNanosBenchmark.sleep1ms                  avgt  100     1430,396 ±    32,876  us/op
```

What is the explanation? As far as it comes from the JavaDoc both `Thread.sleep()` and `LockSupport.parkNanos()` put the thread into `Thread.State.TIMED_WAITING`, so the mechanism under the hood must be the same along with the costs.

Comment: What do you mean by "costs of running" and "overhead"? What exactly do you find suspicious and what would you expect instead?

Comment: By "costs of running" here I mean costs of executing the methods i. e. bringing a thread to sleep and waking it up. In case we call `parkNanos1ms()` it takes us about 100 us on Linux and 500 us on Mac, but when we call `parkNanos100us()` it takes us only 50 us. So the "overhead" is that additional time elapsed apart of delay itself and it varies depending on the delay. This is a confusing point to me.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "costs". More like scheduling inaccuracy, which depends on the particular scheduling policy. IMO, there is nothing surprising in observing accuracy somewhat proportional to the delay. At least, for the non-realtime policies. Btw, did you try different Linux [schedulers](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html)?

Comment: No, I didn't. I'm not that deep in Linux internals )